# Why doesn't SammyJS handle hashes containing slashes the same as normal hashes?

Tags: html, url, browser, single-page-application, sammy.js

Inspired by the example in the [KnockoutJS SPA tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=webmail), I'm trying to use [Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) to wire up some simple behaviour in a single-page application, using the URL hash to keep track of which API endpoint is being invoked. I'm trying to end up with a page history that looks like this:

- http://www.my.app/my_app#/resources
- http://www.my.app/my_app#/resource/some/link
- http://www.my.app/my_app#/resource/some/other/link
- http://www.my.app/my_app#/resource/some/other/link?page=2
- http://www.my.app/my_app#/resource/some/other/link?page=3

In every case, the URL fragment is actually the raw URL that was used to make the API call which rendered the current page.

The problem is, I can't get Sammy's route handling to work properly when the location hash contains a forward-slash character - and I have no idea why. According to [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5), "the characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") are allowed to represent data within the fragment identifier", so it sounds to me like I should just be able to use unescaped slash and question mark characters in the URL fragment.

Here's a complete repro case covering several different scenarios. There's two Sammy routes defined - if my understanding of the syntax is correct, one should capture anything containing a hash and the other should match only the empty route. That's not what's happening, though.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>SammyJS routing demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/sammy-0.7.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#foo">#foo</a> - prints 'foo'</li>
        <li><a href="#/bar">#/bar</a> - prints 'NOPE'</li>
        <li><a href="#!/baz">#!/baz</a> - prints 'NOPE'</li>
        <li><a href="#foo/bar">#foo/bar</a> - prints 'NOPE'</li>
        <li><a href="#foo/bar#bop">#foo/bar#bop</a> - prints 'bop'</li>
        <li><a href="#why?not">#why?not</a> - prints 'why'</li>
        <li><a href="#why?not#zoidberg">#why?not#zoidberg</a> - prints 'why?not#zoidberg'</li>
        <li><a href="#why?not#zoidberg/">#why?not#zoidberg/</a> - prints 'NOPE'</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Sammy(function () {
            this.get('#:url', function () { console.log(this.params.url); });
            this.get('', function () { console.log('NOPE'); });
        }).run();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what I need to do to get Sammy to handle these fragments consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Sammy.js as noted on http://sammyjs.org/docs/routes says "It does not work if you want to match strings that contain ‘/’. If you want that you can use Regexp and ‘splat’", and hence why this example fails.

If however you replace the first `this.get` with `this.get('#(.*)', function () { console.log(this.params['splat']); });` then it works pretty much fine (well, the "#why?not" misses out the not, but that's probably further in the query string and "#why?not#zoidberg" isn't that happy, but I'd say you should stick to a single # in a URL)

https://jsfiddle.net/gymt828r/ demonstrates a fixed instance of this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Sammy params within a URL cannot contain a slash character. If it did, you could not have URLs like "#/path/:var1/other/:var2". Instead, you'll want to use a regex whenever you match your path, as in the example below (see http://sammyjs.org/docs/routes for more info):

```
this.get(/\#(.*)/, function() {
    console.log(this.params['splat']);
});
```

The above will output the URL for each of the following paths:

- http://www.my.app/my_app#/resources
- http://www.my.app/my_app#/resource/some/link
- http://www.my.app/my_app#/resource/some/other/link

Unfortunately, you won't be able to get items following a "?" character using this, though. Those are parsed separately into "this.params". So the following URLs will have "this.params.page" set to the appropriate value:

- http://www.my.app/my_app#/resource/some/other/link?page=2
- http://www.my.app/my_app#/resource/some/other/link?page=3

Unfortunately, you won't be able to have multiple hash in a URL, and Sammy only looks at the portion of the URL starting from the last instance of a hash, thus explaining why "#why?not#zoidberg" works.